# next business day of give date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a task to find the next business day of particular given date. It should exclude the holidays that are listed in holiday table (`mst_holiday`). I have a procedure using decode function to find the next business day when there is continuous holiday or weekend. For example if today is 21-07-2013 Wednesday, if I need to find 5 days later it should display 26-07-2013, if it is a holiday, it should display the successive non holiday.

The sample decode function I have used is below. Please help me to write alternate sql query.

```
DECODE
   (ldate,
    laps.holidaydate, DECODE
       (ldate + 1,
        laps.holidaydate + 1, DECODE
           (ldate + 2,
            laps.holidaydate + 2,ldate+3,ldate+2),ldate+1),ldate);`
```

Comment: Check out this answer, seems like a ready function : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16413949/1026199

Comment: You've got answers on the previous version of the question. This doesn't seem to add anything new. You should explain why those answers aren't useful and modify your original question to give the details requested and more information, not ask the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Do this 3 steps:

1) Generate a range of dates you want to check for example:

```
select to_date(:start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy') + rownum -1
from all_objects
where rownum <= to_date(:end_date,'dd-mon-yyyy')-to_date(:start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy')+1
```

2) Select minus the table with the holidays table

3) Select ordered by date and get the first record

Put it all in one sql Select.

Comment: what does this end date mean? how to minus with holiday table?

Comment: limits the range of dates between you must make sure there is at least 1 bussines day. You could substitute by "where rownum<7". Select MINUS substract the results of select from another: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm