# WHERE 5 business days

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to get the next 5 business days, using sysdate in the WHERE (ie.

```
where trunc(teststart) between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate+4)),
```

but if the range includes Friday, it needs to count weekend days, Saturday & Sunday.

What is the command that will tell you the day of the week when looking at the sysdate or sysdate+3 (or any number)?  How would you accomplish something like this?

Comment: The following my help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898357/calculate-business-days-in-oracle-sqlno-functions-or-procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this calculation because there is no way that oracle know what exactly is a business day. This is because every region has your own hollidays. To do this you will have to create a table calendar and put all days on it marking which ones is business day. Then you can just join your table with this calendar table using a `between` clause

Comment: Is there a command/function that returns 'MON', 0, 'TUE', 1, 'WED', 2, 'THU', 3...etc... that I can test SYSDATE to?

Comment: to_char(sysdate,'D') it will return the number of the day on the week but it depends on the configuration of your database starting day of the week. See this http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html there is a table for every format you can use.

Comment: It actually depends on the NLS-Configuration of your **Session**, not of the database. In order to be sure that you get correct day you have to use function like this `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')`

Comment: You can have default NLS settings that are DB-wide.

Comment: @jimmcnamara That is what I mean. Wernfried you are also right, but if there is no session configuration it will be overrided by the DB configs.

Answer (score 0):

@JorgeCampos point is well taken about day 1. You indicate with MON 0 that Monday is the start of the week, NLS settings on the DB and your locale determine this.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'D'), to_char(sysdate,'DAY') from dual;
```

gives the result you asked for. We have a table that gets the next year populated in December for the next year. Includes all holidays, etc.

```
 JCAL_JOB_DATE                          NOT NULL DATE
 JCAL_USER_ID                                    VARCHAR2(30)
 JCAL_ACTIVITY_DATE                              DATE
 JCAL_BUSINESS_DAY                               VARCHAR2(2)
 JCAL_HOLIDAY                                    VARCHAR2(2)
 JCAL_WEEKEND                                    VARCHAR2(2)
```

This is used to forecast jobs in the future, and some recurring jobs that do not want to run on holidays or weekends for example.

```
select jcal_job_date from jcal where 
    JCAL_JOB_DATE > sysdate
and JCAL_BUSINESS_DAY='Y'
and rownum <6;
```

This is one not-so-good way to get the fifth business day. Fetch You can use a lot of other functions to streamline this.

This kind of table is VERY useful to determine the same information (work, holiday, weekend) in  the past.

Where I am we have holidays that fall on the last Thursday of November and extra holidays are added in there.  Programming for that is hard when compared to a simple lookup that works great.