# how to find the difference between two dates using Oracle sql by excluding weekends

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g

I am using the below code to pick the difference between two dates excluding weekends. However, the below method is not accurate. It gives issues when the difference between the two days are very less, e.g. 2 and it includes Saturday OR Sunday.

```
DAYS= Round((END_TIME-START_TIME)-2*FLOOR((END_TIME-START_TIME)/7)-DECODE(SIGN(TO_CHAR(END_TIME,'D')-
    TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'D')),-1,2,0)+DECODE(TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'D'),7,1,0)-
    DECODE(TO_CHAR(END_TIME,'D'),7,1,0),0)
```

Please help

Comment: What's about public holidays, e.g New Year or Independence Day?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898357/calculate-business-days-in-oracle-sqlno-functions-or-procedure

Comment: hi what is the data type of the value that is returned by `TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'D')` I guess its a varchar, then how is the opreation `TO_CHAR(END_TIME,'D')-TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'D')` possible?