# Want a SQL to get days between 2 date and exclude Saturday and Sunday in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

As the title said, I want to calculate days between 2 dates and exclude weekend(Saturday and Sunday) in Oracle, I have no idea about this at all, can anyone help give an example SQL?

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate rows for all the days between two given dates? Also, are there multiple rows of these two dates - like row1 - d1 to d2, row2 - d3 to d4? Please post some example what you will give as input and what you want as output? Where is the input coming from? a table? is there an id column or any other unique column?

Comment: for example, there are start_date and end_date, I use (end_date - start_date) will get the number of days, so if the duration contains Saturday and Sunday, the result should be (days - 2)

Comment: Please [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42596211/edit) the question and add example data and result

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Change start_date and end_date as per your requirement.

If you want number of weekdays, use

```
  WITH test_data AS
  (
     SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') AS start_date,
            TO_DATE('31-DEC-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') AS end_date  
       FROM dual
  ), 
all_dates AS 
( SELECT td.start_date, td.end_date, td.start_date + LEVEL-1 as week_day
      FROM test_data td
   CONNECT BY td.start_date + LEVEL-1 <=  td.end_date)

   select count(*) from all_dates
    WHERE to_char(week_day, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') NOT IN ('sun' , 'sat')
```

If you want the dates displayed, in the select clause, use

```
select week_day from all_dates
```

How it works:

1. It start adding 1 day to start_date until you reach `end_date`, by using `connect by`/`level` in Oracle.
2. It removes the days which are `saturday` or `sunday`

PS: Refered this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982906/5234334) for it

Answer (score 0):

How about simplifying

"Select * from emp where hiredate between 
To_date(f_date,'dd-mm-yyyy) and to_date(t_date,
'Dd-mm-yyyy') and to_char(hiredate,dy) not in('sat','sun')