# how to calculate number of working days in pure sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in pl-SQL environment to which I have very limited access.

1. I can query the DB (sql statements)
2. I can not create functions or procedures.

For a table with 2 flds:

1. startPeriod
2. endPeriod

I want to calculate work days / business days

(e.g: endPeriod-startPeriod -nonWorkingDays)

Utsav answer feels very helpful :

[Want a SQL to get days between 2 date and exclude Saturday and Sunday in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42596211),

yet I cannot replace the hard coded dates with dynamic dates from my table.

the following query that is based on Utsav answer returns an error message: "Invalid identifier"

```
SELECT t,startPeriod,t.endPeriod,
   (
        With test_data as (select t.startPeriod as start_date,t.endPeriod as end_date from dual ),
        all_dates as (select td.start_date + level-1 
        as week_day from test_data td connect by 
        td.start_date + level-1< td.end_date)
        select count(*) from all_dates where 
        to_char(week_day,'dy', 'nls_date_language-american') not in ('sun','sat') and week_day not in ('01jan2019','02feb2019')
   ) as workingDaysField
FROM dbo.TBL t
```

Comment: What about holidays? Can we ignore them?

Comment: What Oracle Version are you using? Maybe you use Version >=12.1 then you could use the "functions in with clause" feature: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51831374/330315