# adding business days in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two date fields, DATE_FIELD_ONE = 8/30/2018 and DATE_FIELD_TWO = DATE_FIELD_ONE + 20. I need to find what DATE_FIELD_TWO should be if I'm only added 20 business days . How would I accomplish this? I thought maybe trying 'DY' but not sure how to get it to work. Thanks.

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE_FIELD_ONE),'DY')='SAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE_FIELD_ONE),'DY')='SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: What about public holidays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate business days in Oracle SQL(no functions or procedure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898357/calculate-business-days-in-oracle-sqlno-functions-or-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this :

```
select max(date_field_two) as date_field_two
  from
 (
 select date'2018-08-30'+  
    cast(case when to_char(date'2018-08-30'+level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') 
                                              in ('6','7') then 
            0
          else
            level
          end as int) as date_field_two, 
 sum(cast(case when to_char(date'2018-08-30'+level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  
                                               in ('6','7') then 
            0
          else
            1
          end as int)) over (order by level) as next_day
      from dual
    connect by level <= 20*1.5 
-- 20 is the day to be added, every time 5(#of business days)*1.5 > 7(#of week days)
-- 7=5+2<5+(5/2)=5*(1+1/2)=5*1.5 [where 1.5 is just a coefficient might be replaced a greater one like 2]
-- so 4*5*1.5=20*1.5 > 4*7 
  )    
 where next_day = 20;

 DATE_FIELD_TWO
-----------------
   27.09.2018
```

by using `connect by dual` clause.

P.S. Ignored the case for public holidays, which differ from one culture to another , depending on the question being related with only weekends.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/LHD87279)

***Edit :*** Assume you have a national holidays on '2018-09-25' and '2018-09-26' (in this set of days), then consider the following :

```
select max(date_field_two) as date_field_two
  from
 (
 select date'2018-08-30'+  
        (case when to_char(date'2018-08-30'+level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') 
                                              in ('6','7') then 
               0
              when date'2018-08-30'+level in (date'2018-09-25',date'2018-09-26') then
               0
              else
               level
              end) as date_field_two, 
 sum(cast(case when to_char(date'2018-08-30'+level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  
                                               in ('6','7') then 
                0
               when date'2018-08-30'+level in (date'2018-09-25',date'2018-09-26') then
                0 
               else
                1
               end as int)) over (order by level) as next_day
      from dual
    connect by level <= 20*2 
  )    
 where next_day = 20;

 DATE_FIELD_TWO
-----------------
   01.10.2018
```

which iterates one day next, as in this case, unless this holiday coincides with weekend.

Comment: How did you come up with the 1.5?

Comment: @smattiko84 `7=5+2<5+(5/2)=5*(1+1/2)=5*1.5`, this is within a week, you may expand to any other value. In fact the value is not important, you may choose 2 as coefficient also to satisfy the condition.

Comment: If I did want to add a couple usa holidays, how would I modifiy?

Answer (score 0):

you can define workdays to be whatever you like if you use a PL/SQL function

Have a simple prototype here - without any holidays - but it could be adapted for that purpose using the same kind of logic.

```
create or replace function add_business_days (from_date IN date, bd IN integer) return date as 
  fd date := trunc(from_date,'iw'); 
  cnt int := (from_date-fd)+bd-1; 
  ww int := ceil(cnt/5); 
  wd int := mod(cnt,5); 
begin
  return from_date + (ww*7)+wd; 
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you already have an answer, but for what it's worth this is something we deal with all the time and have what has turned out to be a very good solution.

In effect, we maintain a separate table called "work days" that has every conceivable date we would ever compare (and that definition will vary from application to application, of course -- but in any case it will never be "huge" by RDBMS standards).  There is a boolean flag that dictates if the date is a work day or a weekend/holiday, but more importantly there is an index value that only increments on work days.  The table looks like this:

[image]

The advantage to this is transparency and scalability.  If you want the difference between two dates in work days:

```
select
  h.entry_date, h.invoice_date, wd2.workday_index - wd1.workday_index as delta
from
  sales_order_data h
  join util.work_days wd1 on h.sales_order_entry_dte = wd1.cal_date
  join util.work_days wd2 on h.invoice_dte = wd2.cal_date
```

If you need to take a date in a table and add 20 days (like your original problem statement):

```
select
  h.date_field_1, wd2.cal_date as date_field_1_plus_20
from
  my_table h
  join util.work_days wd1 on h.date_field_1 = wd1.cal_date
  join util.work_days wd2 on
    wd1.workday_index + 20 = wd2.workday_index and
    wd2.is_workday
```

(disclaimer, this is in PostgreSQL, which is why I have the boolean.  In Oracle, I'm guessing you need to change that to an integer and say `=1`)

Also, for the bonus question, this also gives two different options for defining "work day," one that rolls forward and another that rolls backwards (hence the workday_index and workday_index_back).  For example, if you *need* something on a Saturday, and Saturday is not a work day, that means you need it on Friday.  Conversely, if something is to be delivered on Saturday, and Saturday is not on a work day, then that means it will be available on Monday.  The context of how to handle non-workdays differs, and this method affords you the option of chosing the right one.

As a final selling point, this option allows you to define holidays as non-work days also...  and you can do this or not do this; it's up to you.  The solution permits either option.  You could theoretically add two more columns for work day index weekend only that gave you both options.