# Oracle SQL get First Business Day date of given date

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get the date of the first business day of a given date .

For example:
**01-AUG-21** is Sunday, so the first business day is **02-AUG-21** .

Comment: Is your only criteria for "business day" that the day is not Saturday/Sunday?  What about holidays for the intended country and/or locality?

Comment: There are a lot of examples regarding a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898357/calculate-business-days-in-oracle-sqlno-functions-or-procedure

Comment: Please define "business day".

Comment: yes only business day from Monday to Friday

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple case statement in SQL or PL/SQL. In the example below, just replace `SYSDATE + LEVEL` with the date you would like to use.

```sql
    SELECT SYSDATE + LEVEL                                                                          AS some_date,
           TO_CHAR (SYSDATE + LEVEL, 'DY')                                                          AS some_day_of_week,
             SYSDATE
           + LEVEL
           + CASE TO_CHAR (SYSDATE + LEVEL, 'DY') WHEN 'SAT' THEN 2 WHEN 'SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS business_day
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 14;
```

```
SOME_DATE    SOME_DAY_OF_WEEK    BUSINESS_DAY
____________ ___________________ ________________
02-JUL-21    FRI                 02-JUL-21
03-JUL-21    SAT                 05-JUL-21
04-JUL-21    SUN                 05-JUL-21
05-JUL-21    MON                 05-JUL-21
06-JUL-21    TUE                 06-JUL-21
07-JUL-21    WED                 07-JUL-21
08-JUL-21    THU                 08-JUL-21
09-JUL-21    FRI                 09-JUL-21
10-JUL-21    SAT                 12-JUL-21
11-JUL-21    SUN                 12-JUL-21
12-JUL-21    MON                 12-JUL-21
13-JUL-21    TUE                 13-JUL-21
14-JUL-21    WED                 14-JUL-21
15-JUL-21    THU                 15-JUL-21
```

Here is a PL/SQL example of the same logic

```sql
DECLARE
    FUNCTION get_business_day (p_date DATE)
        RETURN DATE
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN TRUNC (
                     p_date
                   + CASE TO_CHAR (p_date, 'DY')
                         WHEN 'SAT' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'SUN' THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                     END);
    END;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (get_business_day (p_date => SYSDATE));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: as it is only about 1 week, create a little one-week-calendar and fetch date which is larger than the one entered as a parameter, and which isn't a weekend.

```
with little_calendar as
  (select to_date(:par_datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1 datum
   from dual
   connect by level <= 7
  )
select min(datum)
from little_calendar
where datum > to_date(:par_datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  and to_char(datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') 
      not in ('sat', 'sun');
```

---

A few examples in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> with little_calendar as
  2    (select to_date('&&par_datum', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 7
  5    )
  6  select min(datum)
  7  from little_calendar
  8  where datum > to_date('&&par_datum', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  9    and to_char(datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english')
 10        not in ('sat', 'sun');
Enter value for par_datum: 01.07.2021   --> the 1st working day after 01.07.2021 (Thursday) ...

MIN(DATUM)
---------------
02.07.2021, fri                         --> ... is 02.07.2021 (Friday)

SQL> undefine par_datum
SQL> /
Enter value for par_datum: 02.07.2021   --> working day that follows 02.07.2021 (Friday) ...

MIN(DATUM)
---------------
05.07.2021, mon                         --> ... is 05.07.2021 (Monday)

SQL>
```